# How to fix "Received: 50 (missing previous layer metadata)." error in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to copy the layer from the autoencoder to use to decode the file but i'm getting an error

```
encoded_input = Input(shape=(50,))

decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1](encoded_input)

decoder = Model(50, decoder_layer)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

autoencoder.fit(X, X,
            epochs=50,
            shuffle=True)
```

I'm expecting to copy the layer so that I can decode the file but I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\dalto\Documents\geo4\train.py", line 36, in <module>
decoder = Model(50, decoder_layer)
File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 133, in __init__
super(Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 161, in __init__
self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 458, in _method_wrapper
result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 270, in _init_graph_network
self._validate_graph_inputs_and_outputs()
File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 1521, in _validate_graph_inputs_and_outputs
' (missing previous layer metadata).')
```

ValueError: Input tensors to a Model must come from `tf.keras.Input`. Received: 50 (missing previous layer metadata).

Comment: decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer)